# What is the difference between the -f and -l options of secure-delete srm?

Tags: secure-erase

Regarding the secure-delete command in Linux, what is the difference between `srm -f`, `srm -l` and `srm -fl` ? Which is fastest? Which is most secure?

Comment: Reading the manpage (`man srm`) might be of assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> -f fast (and insecure mode): no /dev/urandom, no synchronize mode.
>
> -l lessens the security. Only two passes are written: one mode with 0xff and a final mode random values.<sup>[Ubuntu Manuals](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/srm.1.html)</sup>